# Performance issue in Google Maps for iOS when more than 840 markers on map

Tags: ios, swift, performance, google-maps

I'm profiling my app and finding that Google Maps (v2.0.1) for iOS is pegging the CPU when creating more than 840 markers on the map.  As soon as I create that 841st marker, CPU peg about 98%.

```
    func loadMarkers() {

    if(mapView != nil) {

        let objects = objectAPI.getObjects()

        for (index, object) in objects.enumerate() {

                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.snippet = object.title
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: object.lat.doubleValue, longitude: object.lng.doubleValue)
                marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())                                        
                marker.map = mapView                
            }
        }
```

The trace shows that it's performance is killed in EntityRenderer::Draw.  Why random 840 markers?  If I render 840 markers or less, then no problem.  Same behavior on Simulator and 6s Plus device.

```
Running Time    Self (ms)       Symbol Name
422370.0ms   98.5%  5.0       -[GMSDisplayLink displayLinkFired:]
422364.0ms   98.5%  7.0        -[GMSEntityRendererView draw]
422351.0ms   98.5%  0.0         -[GMSPhoenixRenderer drawIfNeeded]
422331.0ms   98.5%  341.0            gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer::Draw(bool)
213215.0ms   49.7%  1373.0            (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*)
186073.0ms   43.4%  17786.0            (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::SelectFrame(UIImage*, double, double)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this performance problem is to reuse the uiimage for marker icon:

```
    let objects = objectAPI.getObjects()

    let markerImage = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())

    for (index, object) in objects.enumerate() {

            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.snippet = object.title
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: object.lat.doubleValue, longitude: object.lng.doubleValue)
            marker.icon = markerImage                                        
            marker.map = mapView                
     }
```